# How to replace not found reference "??" in an another constant e.g "REF"?

Tags: cross-referencing

If you in (pdf)latex reference a reference which does not exist (e.g. picture/table/etc), latex will output "??".

How can I replace this "??"  in something else e.g. "REF"? It would be nice if the solution worked for all type of references.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The command responsible for printing **??** is `\@setref`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

%\usepackage{hyperref} % not mandatory, but should go before the patch

% must be done after loading hyperref
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@setref}{??}{REF}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ref{missing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you would like this to apply also to `hyperref`’s `\autoref` command, you additionally need to patch `\HyRef@autosetref`. For instance, `\patchcmd{\HyRef@autosetref}{??}{\color{red}Label not found}{}{}`.